# PHP: How to make my counter start counting from 2 not from 0

Tags: php, symfony

I have a loop in php and I want the index($i) to start counting from 2 instead of the standard 0. How can I achieve my goal? I've tried `$i=2;` but doesn't seem to be working, unfortunately.

Anyone can help? Here's my loop:

```
$crawler->filter('div#product > div.row > div.span6 > div.thumbs > div.image a')->slice(1, 5)->each(function($node, $i) use(&$local, $lowertitle){
    $filename = "images/galatea" . $lowertitle . $i . ".jpg";
    $imageurl = $node->attr('href');
    $theurl = substr($imageurl, 2);

    copy('http://'.$theurl, $filename); 

    $imagesarray = $local['images'][] = $filename;
});
```

Anyone please? :(

Comment: Would you like to loop within your closure?

Comment: Can you show us where you are assigning a value to $i?

Comment: @wiesson I'm sorry I don't know what you mean. My goal is just to make my $i start counting from 2, it now starts from 0. So instead 0-1-2-3 I want 2-3-4-6

Comment: @SGR it happens in the first line of code function($node, $i) maybe you need to scroll to the right a bit :)

Comment: @RyanVincent It's standard from a symfony component DomCrawler, not sure it's the right approach to go change it there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$i is the index, so just do that :

> $filename = "images/galatea" . $lowertitle . ($i+2) . ".jpg";

Comment: Thanks a lot friend!